# How to Start Another Activity While Click on List Item?

Tags: listview, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

I have created Listview and now want to know how we can start another activity when list view item is clicked ? I really don't know how to do coding further. Please guide me and help me. My coding is ,

MainActivity.Java

```
package com.topitideas.newlistview;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity{

        ListView list;
        String[] itemname ={
                "Safari",
                "Camera",
                "Global",
                "FireFox",
                "UC Browser",
                "Android Folder",
                "VLC Player",
                "Cold War"

        };

        Integer[] imgid={
                R.drawable.pic1,
                R.drawable.pic2,
                R.drawable.pic3,
                R.drawable.pic4,
                R.drawable.pic5,
                R.drawable.pic6,
                R.drawable.pic7,
                R.drawable.pic8,


        };
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, imgid);
            list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
            list.setAdapter((ListAdapter) adapter);

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String Slecteditem= itemname[+position];


                }
            });
        }



        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

CustomListAdapter.java

```
> package com.topitideas.newlistview;
> 
> 
>         import android.app.Activity;
>         import android.view.LayoutInflater;
>         import android.view.View;
>         import android.view.ViewGroup;
>         import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
>         import android.widget.ImageView;
>         import android.widget.TextView;
> 
> public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
> 
>     private final Activity context;
>     private final String[] itemname;
>     private final Integer[] imgid;
> 
>     public CustomListAdapter(MainActivity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
>         super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);
>         // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
> 
>         this.context=context;
>         this.itemname=itemname;
>         this.imgid=imgid;
>     }
> 
>     public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
>         LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
>         View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);
> 
>         TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
>         ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
>         TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
> 
>         txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
>         imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
>         extratxt.setText("Description "+itemname[position]);
>         return rowView;
> 
>     }; }
```

mylist.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#33CC33" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Intent and start it

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", "value");
startActivity(intent);
```

Put this in your onItemClick

In NextActivity:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null)
{
    String myParam = extras.getString("key");
}
```

Comment: Got it thanks an can you please drop the code how we can pass some data to NextActivity with putExtra